# Can I strike the opponent's pieces directly without penalty?

Tags: carrom

Let's say I have my black coin near the pot but there is a white coin which is blocking it from my strike. Can I pot my black coin by striking only the white coin?

Answer (score 1):

**This is fine.**

Based on these [rules](http://icf-media.beepworld.de/laws-of-carrom.htm); it doesn't matter which pieces the Striker does or doesn't touch. Rewards/penalties only care about what's pocketed (or overboard).

Answer (score 0):

yes you can. But if your striker only touches opponent's carrommen,then there will be a foul.You need to touch atleast one of your carrommen or red